# Apply CSS hover on tbody (without th's)

Tags: html, css

I want to highlighet only the `body` of my table and exclude the first `tr`(that contains only the `th`), my table:

```
<table id = "routes">
<!-- this part will not be highlighted on hover-->
<tr>
  <th>env</th>
  <th>route</th>
</tr>
```

and the body:

```
<!-- this part will be highlighted on hover -->
<tbody ng-repeat="i in list">
<tr>
  <td>{{i.id}}</td>
  <td>{{i.route}}</td>
</tr>
```

My css that works on all the table(include the `th`):

```
th, td{
  padding:12px;
}
tr:hover{
  backround-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @shershen - is there somthing wrong with my post?

Comment: I've edited the post title and removed unneeded 'angular' tag that's it. no downvoies from me if you mean this

Comment: Thanks, the angular tag was for ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `tbody` element that wraps body, than just add `thead` for header and apply css for `tbody`

```css
tbody:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set css for first-child `<tr>` like this

```
th, td{
  padding:12px;
}
tr:hover{
  backround-color:#f5f5f5;
}
tr:first-child:hover{
  backround-color:transparent;//or your default color
}
```

In the above code `tr:hover` will apply css on all the `<tr>` and `tr:first-child:hover` will apply css on first `<tr>`.

---

Or if you are using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags then simply use css like this

```
tbody tr:hover{
  backround-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

This will effect only tr which comes under `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here, it's `background-color` no `backround-color`

```
tr:hover{
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

[You can do like this](https://jsfiddle.net/mj86L5uw/2/)

```
th, td{
  padding:12px;
}
tr:hover{
  background-color:red;
}
tr:first-child:hover{
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your body and give styles to TR for that area only. Like

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in list" class="myTableBody">
```

Now add hover effect as follow.

```
.myTableBody tr:hover{
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

There was typo in "background" word of CSS style.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
th, td {
padding:12px;

}

tbody > tr > td:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try with this below css will may help you.

```
#routes tbody:hover{
  background-color : black;
  color : white;
}
```